# Getting 'None' as the result for my stored procedure

Tags: python, mysql

I have a stored procedure with 2 input parameters and 1 output parameter. I'm calling the stored procedure through python with mysql connector.

The procedure accepts a month and a year and return the sum of a certain column during that period.

This works as expected in MySql Workbench but when I run the same query in python it returns **'None'**

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

self.args = ('October','2021',0)

mycursor.callproc('calc_sum', self.args)

mycursor.execute('SELECT @_calc_sum_0, @_calc_sum_1, @_calc_sum_2')

result = mycursor.fetchall()

print ('sum_calc_is',result)
```

Running the above block of code return a tuple made up of 'None'

```
[(None, None, None)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you shoud check the manual again https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need in something like:

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
self.args = ('October','2021',0)
mycursor.execute('SET @_calc_sum_0 := %s, @_calc_sum_1 := %s, @_calc_sum_2 := %s', self.args)
mycursor.callproc('calc_sum(@_calc_sum_0, @_calc_sum_1, @_calc_sum_2)')
# or maybe
# mycursor.execute('CALL calc_sum(@_calc_sum_0, @_calc_sum_1, @_calc_sum_2)')
mycursor.execute('SELECT @_calc_sum_0, @_calc_sum_1, @_calc_sum_2')
result = mycursor.fetchall()
print ('sum_calc_is',result)
```

First `mycursor.execute` assign parameters values into user-defined variables. Adjust the parameters insertion syntax if it is not correct.

Next `mycursor.callproc` calls the stored procedure specifying above UDVs (not literal values!) as its parameters. SP alters their values during the execution. Maybe you must use `mycursor.execute('CALL calc_sum(@_calc_sum_0, @_calc_sum_1, @_calc_sum_2)')` there, because you do not need in transferring parameters values.

Next `mycursor.execute` retrieves the values of UDVs after SP execution.

Comment: Thanks. Using `mycursor.execute('CALL calc_sum(@_calc_sum_0, @_calc_sum_1, @_calc_sum_2)')` worked for me.